# Hash slash (#/text) wipes out url leaving domain with /text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, url, rubygems

Working on some rails app where observing a weird issue, when there is a  “**#/whatever**” at the end of a url, it wipes out the rest of the url.
For e.g., if we have below URL

```
https://www.example.com/sub/123/cou/321/something
```

and we add `#/hello?how-are-you`, like

```
https://www.example.com/sub/123/cou/321/something#/hello?how-are-you
```

and press enter, url changes to:

```
https://www.example.com/hello?how-are-you
```

On all environments. Tested this in other rails app and .NET apps where this is not observed, below are details of my ROR app:

rails 4.2.7.1, ruby 2.3.1 and many gems

**Question:**
How can I prevent this behaviour, as this send wrong url.referrer to server

Comment: Seeing as the fragment doesn't get to the server you probably have a JavaScript issue, possibly related to one of those "many gems".

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Fragments are local to the web browser, that's their whole point. They never get sent to the server, so there is nothing you can do on the server to get them.